# Is there a way to make this code more "Neat"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The user inserts multiple values and the program determines how many positive values, negative values, zero values, even values, odd values, and the min, max, average, and total of those values. The code works, however it's quite messy.

```
negative=0
zero=0
positive=0
even=0
odd=0
max=0
min=0
a=int(input('Number of values:'))
b=int(input('First value:'))
if b==0:
    zero=1
if b<0:
    negative=1
if b>0:
    positive=1
if b%2==0:
    even=1
else:
    odd=1
if b>max:
        max=b
total=b
for x in range(a-1):
    b=int(input('Next value:'))
    total+=b
    if b==0:
        zero+=1
    if b==0:
          zero+=1
    if b<0:
          negative+=1
    if b>0:
          positive+=1
    if b%2==0:
          even+=1
    else:
         odd+=1
    if b>max:
        max=b
    if b<max:
        min=b
print('Negative values:',negative)
print('Zero values:',zero)
print('Positive values:',positive)
print('Even values:',even)
print('Odd values:',odd)
print('Total:',total)
print('Minimum:',min)
print('Maximum:',max)
print('Average:',total/a)
```

Comment: The only thing that feels messy is the lack of whitespace.

Comment: ok thank, it's been noted. do you think there's too much repetition?

Comment: You could use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: why do you run everything once outside the loop? You can by the least store the numbers in a list, then run the loop on all of them (rather than write the entire code twice)

Comment: because the code doesn't add the  'First value:' to the rest of the values

Comment: You're naming conventions for `a` and `b` also add to some confusion here

Comment: Hey! Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a good home for this kind of questions!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because posts looking for critique/review of working code are related to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Being a better fit for code review does not imply it is off topic here. I would go with "too broad".

Comment: ah sorry, guys, I'll make sure to post it under code review next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts of the script essentially doing the same thing, except that you're asking the user `"First Value"` instead of `"Next value"`. So I would just merge them together in a loop and determine what msg to use.

There's also a lack of white space everywhere which makes it harder to read. Check out Python's [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) guide to standard conventions.

You can also use more descriptive variable names so it's more readable at a glance.

Also be careful naming your variables `min` and `max`. Those are already built-in methods in Python that you're overriding.

```
negative = 0
zero = 0
positive = 0
even = 0
odd = 0
maxVal = 0
minVal = 0
total = 0

count = int(input('Number of values:'))

for i in range(count):
    if i == 0:
        msg = 'First value:'
    else:
        msg = 'Next value:'

    val = int(input(msg))

    total += val

    if val == 0:
        zero += 1

    if val < 0:
        negative += 1

    if val > 0:
        positive += 1

    if val % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1

    if val > maxVal:
        maxVal = b

    if val <= minVal <= val and val < maxVal:
        minVal = val

print('Negative values:', negative)
print('Zero values:', zero)
print('Positive values:', positive)
print('Even values:', even)
print('Odd values:', odd)
print('Total:', total)
print('Minimum:', minVal)
print('Maximum:', maxVal)
print('Average:', total / count)
```

Comment: how is i equal to zero?

Comment: Because we're taking the `range` of the number of values the user wants to put in. So no matter what number is input, the first time the loop iterates `i` will always equal to `0`. Try a quick search on what `range` does if you're still unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I made a rendition of your code that in my mind is neater, this way you aren't just storing values you have a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that remembers all the values put in and the number of times they were used. Also fixed your whitespace and `times_to_run` is more descriptive than `a` and `value` is more descriptive than `b`. I also just used the iteration number you're on as the `n'th` number being input

```
from collections import Counter

total = 0
all_numbers = Counter()

times_to_run = int(input('Number of values: '))

for x in range(times_to_run):
    value = int(input(f'Value {x + 1}: '))
    total += value
    all_numbers[value] += 1

negative = sum(all_numbers[n] for n in all_numbers if n < 0)
zero = all_numbers[0]
positive = sum(all_numbers[n] for n in all_numbers if n > 0)
even = sum(all_numbers[n] for n in all_numbers if abs(n) % 2)
odd = sum(all_numbers[n] for n in all_numbers if not abs(n) % 2)
max = max(all_numbers)
min = min(all_numbers)

print()
print('Negative values:',negative)
print('Zero values:',zero)
print('Positive values:',positive)
print('Even values:',even)
print('Odd values:',odd)
print('Total:',total)
print('Minimum:',min)
print('Maximum:',max)
print('Average:',total / times_to_run)
```

To test:

```
Number of values: 10
Value 1: -1
Value 2: -1
Value 3: 5
Value 4: 2
Value 5: 0
Value 6: 3
Value 7: 55
Value 8: 8
Value 9: 10
Value 10 :4

Negative values: 2
Zero values: 1
Positive values: 7
Even values: 5
Odd values: 5
Total: 85
Minimum: -1
Maximum: 55
Average: 8.5
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, buddy your code looks much better and professional than mine lol

Comment: No problem, hopefully, this helps you grasp how to use pythons many libraries. If you have trouble understanding anything let me know!

Comment: I exactly don't really know how to use the counter as I just started coding

Comment: but don't worry I'll figure it out

Comment: If you know what a `dict` is, it's a `dict` that assigns a *`number_of_occurances`* integer to a key automatically. and if the key doesn't exist it defaults to 0.

Comment: oh, I see. I think I understand now. I appreciate your help Jab!

Comment: All of what I used are either [built-in-functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), or a [built-in/pre-packaged-library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html). Other than the [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but that link is also in the docs.

Comment: Wish you luck! Hope this helped

Comment: thanks! Um, quick question do you have any recommendation on how I could improve my python programming skills?

Comment: Other than [the](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python) [many](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp) and free [training](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) [courses](https://www.learnpythonthehardway.org/) I suggest just practice and google/search here when you have a question. There many ins and outs that beginners have to learn and wrap their brain around it takes some time but you'll be proficient in no time.